# Relation between continuity and connection between topologies

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

If $X$ is a set and $\tau_1,\tau_2$ two topologies on $X$. What does it mean to put the continuity of the identic map on $X$ (i.e $id_X(x)=x\forall x\in X$) in a relation to the comparability fo two topologies (in our case $\tau_1,\tau_2$)

Comment: To perhaps understand your question better, are you asking, what do we know about the map $\mbox{Id}_X\colon (X,\tau_1)\rightarrow (X,\tau_2)$ given by $\mbox{Id}_X(x)=x$ given two distinct topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$?

Comment: Yes exactly, there must be relation which includ continuity and a distinction between the two topologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the identity $(X,\tau_1)\to(X,\tau_2)$ is continuous, then the preimage of each open set in the codomain, that is a set in $\tau_2$, is an open set in the domain, i.e. an element of $\tau_1$. So $\tau_2$ is coarser than $\tau_1$.

If you know how to characterize continuity locally, then this means that for every $x\in X$ and every neighborhood of $x$ w.r.t. $\tau_2$ there is a neighborhood of $x$ w.r.t. $\tau_1$ contained in the given neighborhood, which means that the local basis is finer.

Answer (score 2):

The identity map being continuous means that every open set in $\tau_2$ is also open in $\tau_1$. This can also be stated as "Topology $\tau_2$ is weaker than topology $\tau_1$". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaker_topology .

Comment: Thanks, so you mean that $\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$? Do you have a proof for this relation?

Comment: It follows almost immediately from the definition of a continuous function.

Comment: Actually, $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$. And as Daniel Rust said, it follows straight from the definition of continuous function.